# Storing data on multiple pages with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I'm building a business planner based on a blog model. I can't however do it over multiple pages. On page 1, when the user clicks "Next", it's like clicking "Post". The data is stored and added to the list of other business plans, or "posts". One the first page, the data is stored by "Insert"ing it into the database. I thought maybe I could simply "Update" the database on page 2 and so on to eliminate multiple listed "posts" or business plans. The data is being stored from the first page, but not the second page. If I add the data for each page using "INSERT INTO..." that works, but each pages is collected as a separate business plan, or multiple posts. Any advice is appreciated.

Here's Page 1:

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    include_once("db.php");    

if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
    $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
    $compName = strip_tags($_POST['compName']);
    $createdBy = strip_tags($_POST['createdBy']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);

    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$title);
    $compName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$compName);
    $createdBy = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$createdBy);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$phone); 

    $date = date('l jS \of F Y h:i A');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO plans (title, date, compName, createdBy, phone) VALUES('$title', '$date', '$compName', '$createdBy', '$phone')";

    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    header("Location: post2.php");
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<div class="container">
<head>
  <title>Create Business Plan</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Create a new business plan</h2>
    <form action="post1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <br /><br />
        <p>Plan Title:  <input name="title" type="text" autofocus size="48"></p>
        <p>Company Name:  <input name="compName" type="text" autofocus size="48"></p>
        <p>Business Type: <input placeholder="Ie. Inc. (USA) or Oy (Finland)" name="bizType" type="text" autofocus size="48"></p>           
        <p>Created By:  <input name="createdBy" type="text" autofocus size="48"></p>
        <p>Phone:  <input name="phone" type="text" autofocus size="48"></p>
        <br /><br />

        <form action="<?php 'post2.php=?pid=$id'; ?>">
        <input name="post" type="submit" value="Next">
        </form>
        <br /><br />
    </form>

</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Here's Page 2:

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    include_once("db.php");

    if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
        $marketPlan = strip_tags($_POST['marketPlan']);
        $economics = strip_tags($_POST['economics']);
        $products = strip_tags($_POST['products']);
        $customers = strip_tags($_POST['customers']);

        $marketPlan = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$marketPlan);
        $economics = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$economics);
        $products = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$products);
        $customers = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$customers);

        $date = date('l jS \of F Y h:i A');

        $sql = "UPDATE plans SET marketPlan='$marketPlan', economics='$economics', products='$products', customers='$customers' WHERE id=$pid";

        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        header("Location: post3.php"); //CHANGE LOCATION FOR NEXT PAGE
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <div class="container">
    <head>
      <title>Create Business Plan</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>The Marketing Plan</h2>
        <form action="post2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <br /><br />            
        <h4>Market Research</h4>
        <p>The marketing plan requires intensive research for the type of industry your business wants to enter. It is very dangerous to assume that you are already well informed about your intended market. Market research is vital to make sure you are up to date. Use the business planning process as your opportunity to uncover data and to question your marketing efforts.</p>
  <textarea name="marketPlan" rows="15" cols="100"></textarea></p><hr />

<h4>Economics</h4>
                <p>What is the total size of your market? What percent of market share will you have? (This is important only if you think you will be a major factor in the market.) What is currently in demand in your target market? What are the trends in target market—growth, consumer preferences, and in product development? Growth potential and opportunity for a business of your size. 
<textarea name="economics" rows="15" cols="100"></textarea><hr />

<h4>Products</h4>
<p>In the <i>Products and Services</i> section, you described your products and services from your point of view. Now describe them from how your customers see them.</p><br /><textarea name="products" rows="15" cols="100"></textarea></p><hr />

<h4>Customers</h4>
<p>Identify your targeted customers, their characteristics, and their geographical location. This is known as customer demographics.</p>
<textarea name="customers" rows="15" cols="100"></textarea></p>

<input name="post" type="submit" value="Next">
</form>

    </body>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do some thing like this, rather than inserting and updating the data to database, store the values in session variables, i mean

example :

```
$_SESSION["title"] = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
```

store every option in session variable like this until you reach the last page.

finally in the last page

insert it to the db. like this,

```
insert into table ('title',.....) values ($_SESSION["title"],....);
```

always use sessions when you want to pass data across multiple pages.

Comment: Thanks @Charles_R! Quick question for you. For the $_SESSION["title"] = strip_tags($_POST['title']); I noticed I was getting a lot of errors saying, "undefined index" and then mentioning the line. I have played with it and I've done both this: `$_SESSION['$title'] = strip_tags($_POST['title']);` with the `$` in front of title and this: `$_SESSION['title'] = strip_tags($_POST['title']);`  without the dollar sign. Does it affect the performance of the strip_tags function if the dollar sign is present or not? Same for mysqli_real_escape_string. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MangoPie sorry mate, actually i don't know much about the performance variation. but i guess it won't vary that much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing right only. First post have to insert those details in table, next post update what are fields you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

in second page you have to get the id from your url

```
if (isset($_GET['pid']))
   $pid = $_GET['pid'];
```

as you try to update an id that doesnt is defined

Comment: *sigh* Posting IDs through the URL is so insecure it should be forbidden. How do you think all those dataleaks occur?

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the ID of the newly created record to the next page; the most secure way is probably to store it in the session. So, on page one, change this:

```
mysqli_query($db, $sql);
```

To

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$_SESSION['new_plan_id'] = $query->insert_id;
```

Then, in your second page query the ID again

```
if (isset($_SESSION['new_plan_id']))
{
  $pid = $_SESSION['new_plan_id'];
}
else
{
  die('No valid session');
}
```

After a user finished his or her plan, remove the `new_plan_id` from the session. You may also want to add session_start() to a global include so it is always enabled.